# How do you say "homebrewer" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

I know that cervecero is brewer, *cerveza casera* is the homebrewed beer, *hacer cerveza* is brewing (making beer), but how do you call the person who makes beer at home? Cervezero casero?

Comment: ¿Caservezero? :-D

Comment: elaborador casero de cerveza https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaboraci%C3%B3n_casera_de_bebidas_alcoh%C3%B3licas Se usa elaborador porque brewer es la person que elabora una bebida.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La traducción del hobby en cuestión sería "Elaboración casera de bebidas alcohólicas", al menos de acuerdo a wikipedia, que ha [traducido al español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaboraci%C3%B3n_casera_de_bebidas_alcoh%C3%B3licas) de esta manera [el artículo en inglés Homebrewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrewing).

Muchas de las profesiones relacionadas con la elaboración de bebidas espirituosas (como [alewife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alewife_(trade))) no tienen traducción o equivalente en español más allá de "maestro cervecero". Hay una cierta dificultad en traducir "brew" al español (sería "*elaborar* cerveza" o incluso "fermentar". En inglés "brew" se puede referir a café, y en español lo dejaríamos simplemente como "elaborar").

Así que no queda más remedio que añadir "caseras" o "en casa" para ese modificador de "(at) home" y clarificar que la elaboración es de este tipo de bebidas (frente a ortas que se distingan con un nombre distinto debido a su tipo, proceso de elaboración, como [*destilación*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DTljaHR) frente a [*fermentación*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HmGWTc5), etc.).

Para alguien que hace esto a pequeña escala (por necesidad si lo hace en su propia casa) podría decirse que es un **cervecero aficionado** (desde luego no un *maestro* cervecero, que es profesional.

> [cervecero, ra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8P2hrKH)
>
> 2. adj. Que hace o vende cerveza
>
> [aficionado, da](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0xTQUAN)
>
> 2. adj. Que cultiva o practica, sin ser profesional, un arte, oficio, ciencia, deporte

Y por supuesto tienes también

> [licorero, ra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NGcPbpy)
>
> 2. m. y f. Persona que fabrica o vende licores (‖ bebidas espiritosas).

Para los casos en que alguien fabrica por ejemplo su propio licor destilado en lugar de cerveza (fermentada).

Comment: Pero un "cervecero aficionado" esta alguien a que le gusta la cerveza mucho tambien, verdad?

Comment: Definitivamente hay ambigüedad en ese término, y es posible que necesites clarificar debido a lo poco ordinario de ese hobby. Desde luego "cervecero aficionado" puede ser un "aficionado a la cerveza" y no solo un _elaborador casero_ de la misma (que sería otra manera de explicar _homebrewer_).

Comment: No creo que aficionado funcione aqui. That is amateur brewer.

Answer (score 3):

Productor artesanal de cerveza

Comment: I think that is nearer to a translation of the English "craft brewer" or "micro brewer" than home brewer.

Answer (score 0):

Por ampliar horizontes:

En el mundillo de la informática  **homebrew** se puede traducir por **casero** y se entiende como:

*Software de todo tipo creado por programadores aficionados o expertos para cualquier plataforma. En algunos casos son versiones de prueba compartidas como freeware o shareware que se distribuyen libremente por internet.*

Tenemos el caso del club de computadores caseros **Homebrew Computer Club** (HCC). Club creado por Gordon French y Fred Moore con la idea de mantener un foro abierto en el que pudieran reunirse personas interesadas en los computadores. Empezó a celebrar sus reuniones en marzo de 1975, en el garaje de Gordon French, en Menlo Park, condado de San Mateo, California, USA. En estas reuniones sus miembros compartían ideas, hardware y software hechos por ellos mismos. Gente que luego tendría papeles muy importantes en el desarrollo de la informática participaron como miembros en este club, como Adam Osborne, Steve Jobs o Steve Wozniak.

http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=Homebrew%20Computer%20Club&Tp=C&Or=0